# BufferedReader, how many bytes read?

Tags: android, bufferedreader

I'm using an `AsynkTast` to download a set of CSV lines and want keep track of how many bytes that has been read in total.

```
while ((string = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    bytesRead += ?;
}
```

How would I access the line total bytes?

I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate but I can only seem to find questions where the answer is in relation to an `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
while ((string = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    bytesRead += (string.getBytes().length);
}
```

Comment: Depends on how precise you want to be. If you want to include line separators, after each line is read, add the byte count in system property line.separator. There is still some uncertainty at the end of file: there may not be a separator there. If you happen to want to be absolutely precise, you can override BufferedReader and count the bytes there.

Comment: Also beware that the `String.getBytes()` method ["Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) - so the return value might contain a different byte sequence than that which was read by the BufferedReader if the original InputStream used a different encoding.